# Confidence interval for summation of time series

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, prophet

I have three time-series of denoting forecast means with confidence intervals around them. I want to add these three models and get a confidence interval for the final model. How should I approach that?

I have tried:

- using the usual square root of the summation of variances plus covariances for each point in time, but that returned a much wider uncertainty interval than it makes sense (the summation of all consumption means falling entirely well within two standard deviations). Also, the distribution of each point in time is not normal.
- Adding sample forecasts from each model (these are Facebook Prophet models, so it's easy to sample forecasts) and using them to estimate the confidence intervals but then remembered that the samples wouldn't be correlated.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You need a joint model, you can't derive the distribution of the sum from the marginals alone. Also, you mean prediction interval, not confidence interval.

Comment: I see. The issue is that Prophet does not give the option of a joint model... I was wondering if there was a way of applying a correlation structure to independently sampled models. What do you think?

Comment: Did you average the variances by dividing their sum by 3 prior to taking the square root? That would be, without covariances, the root mean squared error, and with them, a covariance corrected RMSE.

Comment: I don't think we should average the variances, do we? This derivation seems to suggest otherwise https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2878148